# Add CustomFragment to Layout at index

Tags: android, android-fragments

**Scenario**:

I have a LinearLayout and wish to add CustomFragments (all of the same Class) dynamically.
I store said Fragments in an ArrayList (`fragSteps`) to handle them easier.
Since I need to enumerate, add and delete them I wish to keep them all just in the LinearLayout so I don't need to handle any Overhead.

What I am searching for is the Fragment equivalent of `Layout.addView(View, Index)` OR a way to easily move the position of Fragments after they are attached to the Layout.

**Code**:

To add and remove the Fragments I only use these two lines:

```
public void addFragment(int index)
{
    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add
            (R.id.layout, fragSteps.get(index + 1)).commit();
}

public void removeFragment(int index)
{
    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(fragSteps.get(index)).commit();
}
```

If anything is needed, state it in the comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as a sollution try to use every fragment inside a view so you can use views to take control

```js
public View addFrag(FragmentSecondParent fragment)
    {
        View view=new View(getActivity());
        FragmentManager fragmentManager=getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction=fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.add(view.getId(),fragment).commit();
        return view;
    }
    public void removeFrag(View view)
    {
        view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
    
//to use the above Methods
{
List<View> views=new ArrayList();
        LinearLayout layout=findViewById(...);
        //add these view to a List to get them just by the index
        View view=addFrag(new FragmentSecondParent());
        views.add(view);
        layout.add(view);
        }
```

Comment: Have it integrated using a TableRow as the View.
But I think about it as a sort of hack. Gonna accept it while nothing better turns up. Thank you!